# How can I access args from trait?

Tags: scala

The following code:

```
trait TestMainArgs extends App {
  println(s"args are: $args") // I need to have a generic main in trait which refers to args...
}

object MyRealMainObj extends TestMainArgs {
  // I do not want to call the generic main from objects this would mean I would need to call them from every object which extendfs TestMainArgs
}
```

prints:

```
args are: null
```

While the following:

```
trait TestMainArgs extends App {
}

object MyRealMainObj extends TestMainArgs {
  println(s"args are: $args")
}
```

prints:

```
args are: [Ljava.lang.String;@f82f98
```

So how can I access args from the trait?

I want to put the logic of the `"main"` only in the super `trait` and I don't want code duplication like calling from every object which extends app the super main, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Per http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App, it looks like you might want to look into the functionality of DelayedInit (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.DelayedInit).  I can't say I have any experience with it but perhaps someone else can shed some light on it.  Edit: I think the answer lies in App's source: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/App.scala (I'll write an answer if I figure out exactly what this is doing before someone else does)

Comment: The fastest solution (or as a variant) to change `trait` to `class`, by the reasons below (in the answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option that is also deprecated is to override `main`:

```
trait TestMainArgs extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(s"args are: ${args(0)} from test")
    super.main(args)
  }
}
```

The problem is that the way traits are compiled, the constructor is triggered before the main object, which is where `args` is set. There appears to be no non-deprecated means to do this...

Answer (score 3):

The answer lies in looking at both [DelayedInit](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5e0880fe05fb65a8757721be7e5be6a3259c19a8/src/library/scala/DelayedInit.scala) and [App](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/App.scala) in the Scala source.    The real gem lies in the doc comment at the start of DelayedInit:

```
Example:
 *  {{{
 *    trait Helper extends DelayedInit {
 *      def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
 *        println("dummy text, printed before initialization of C")
 *        body // evaluates the initialization code of C
 *      }
 *    }
 *
 *    class C extends Helper {
 *      println("this is the initialization code of C")
 *    }
 *
 *    object Test extends App {
 *      val c = new C
 *    }
 *  }}}
 *
 *  Should result in the following being printed:
 *  {{{
 *    dummy text, printed before initialization of C
 *    this is the initialization code of C
 *  }}}
```

So, just extend DelayedInit, follow the warnings you see in App (specifically, don't override args in your extending class), and you should be able to access them just as App does:

```
@deprecatedOverriding("main should not be overridden", "2.11.0")
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  this._args = args
  //other stuff goes here as you like
}
```

However, if you do it like this, be aware that it is deprecated, like it says there, so you run the risk of losing the functionality in future versions of Scala.